# How to generate documentation with references using docfx

Tags: c#, asp.net, documentation, docfx

I am trying to generate documentation for .net project (multi layer). But I am not able to see reference class information in generated documentation with docfx.

Eg:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ServiceLayer;

namespace testApplication.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Home COntroller
    /// </summary>
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Index Method
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Class1 cls1 = new Class1();
            //calling testmethod.
            string abc = cls1.testmethod("testing");
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

the above code is referencing ServiceLayer. using that I am calling testmethod. But Documentation is not showing, this class is using ServiceLayer Reference.

and is there any way to show comments in "//" also in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link: https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/spec/metadata_dotnet_spec.html

The metadata defined for .net include the declarations of:

> Namespaces
>
> Types, including class, struct, interface, enum, delegate
>
> Type members, including field, property, method, event

All these are annotated with the `///` XML comment. Since this is an api descriptor, it makes sense to include only those